# How to modify the URL and one Query Var at the same time with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect a URL path and modify just one query var at the same time.

I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)id=(.*)$
RewriteRule /check/report /report?%1order_id%2
```

Old URL is:

```
/check/report/?id=5914f5&CC=91D36579
```

New URL needs to be:

```
/report/?order_id=5914f5&CC=91D36579
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^check/report/?$ /report?order_id=%1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks @anubhava that's very close.  It swaps id= with order_id= but it doesn't bring in the second query var &cc=

Comment: Fixed with @anubhava's help.

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+)(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^check/report/?$ /report?order_id=%1 [L,NC,R=302]